# ThreeJS raycast to detect animation model?

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I want to detect when the user in my ThreeJS is looking at one of the animation models. Currently I am using this code:

```js
            ourRaycaster.setFromCamera(g_Mouse, g_ThreeJsCamera);
            
            g_AryObjectsLookedAt = ourRaycaster.intersectObjects(g_ThreeJsScene.children, true);
```

The problem is that although the raycaster *will* detect any collisions between the current camera line of sight and a child object in the animation models group, it will *not* intersect with any empty spaces in the group.  Although this makes sense from a technical point of view, it doesn't match what we do as humans when looking at an object.  When we look at an object, we mentally draw a shape around the *overall* object and if we are looking inside that pseudo-shape we feel that we are looking at the object.

For example, if you have a big head and wide shoulders, but a very thin neck, if I focus momentarily at the space alongside your neck I still feel that I am looking at "you".

What I need is a raycaster that when it passes through an animation model's group of children, does approximately the same thing.

Here is a concrete example.  I am using the sample robot animation model from the ThreeJS examples.  It has a really big head.  When I do the raycast from this distance, **no** part of the robot is in the intersecting objects list:

[image: robot not detected]

But if I get right up "in its face", it **is** detected (it's "face" is detected):

[image]

This is technically accurate but I need something a lot more forgiving so I can create proper logic for interactions between animation model and the user.  How can I do this without having to iterate manually with every animation model in the virtual scene?

Comment: `Raycaster` has a `ray` property which is the ray used to perform the intersection. [`Ray`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Ray) has methods like `intersectBox` and `intersectSphere`, which can be used to check for intersection with a mesh's bounding box or bounding sphere, which _usually_ take up more space than the mesh its self. You will likely need to adjust for transformations. You could also make a `Box3` or `Sphere` to contain the entire model (if it's made of multiple meshes) and use the same technique to detect intersections.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks.  Are there any samples I can look at somewhere?  That would be a big help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any live examples that do exactly this. That's one reason why I made it a comment rather than an answer.